# Как в русском языке понять словосочетание "соответствующий год"? Какому периоду он соответствует?

Tags: семантика, словосочетания, значение

Сведения об организации производственного контроля за соблюдением требований промышленной безопасности представляются в письменной форме либо в форме электронного документа, подписанного усиленной квалифицированной электронной подписью, в федеральные органы исполнительной власти в области промышленной безопасности или их территориальные органы ежегодно **до 1 апреля соответствующего календарного года**. Требования к форме представления сведений об организации производственного контроля за соблюдением требований промышленной безопасности устанавливаются федеральным органом исполнительной власти в области промышленной безопасности.

Answer (score 1):

Имеется в виду временнóе окно возможности для представления сведений. Фразой обозначена и его периодичность (ежегодность), и продолжительность — с 1 января до 31 марта — в **соответствующем датам** году.